# How to find where a process is stuck using DDD

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, ddd-debugger

I have a TCP Svr process written in C and running on CentOS 5.5. It acts as a TCP Server for external clients and also does some IPC communication with other processes in the system using Unix Domain Sockets it has establised.  It's not a multi threaded process.  It does one task at a time.  There's an epoll_wait() I use to listen for requests on either the TCP socket or any of the IPC sockets it has established with internal processes.  When the epoll_wait() function breaks,I process the request for whoever it is and then go back into epoll_wait()

I have a TCP Client that connects to this Process from outside (not IPC). It connects sucessfully, sends a request msg, gets a response back.  I've put this in an infinite loop 
just to test out its robustness etc.

After a while, the TCP Server stops responding to requests coming from TCP Client.  The TCP client connects successfully, sends a request message, but it doesnt get any response msg back from the TCP server.

So I reckon the TCP server is stuck somewhere else, trying to do something and has not returned to the epoll_wait() to process
other requests coming in.  I've tried to figure it out using logs, but thats not helping me understand where exactly the process is stuck.

So I wanted to use any debugger that can give me some information (function name would be great), as to what the process is doing. Putting breakpoints, is overwhelming cause the TCP Server process has tons of files and functions....

I'm trying to use DDD on CentOS 5.5, to figureout whats going on.  I attach to the process successfully. Then I click on "Step" or "Stepi" or "Next" button....
but nothing happens....

btw when I use Eclipse for debugging, and attach to this process (or any process), I always get "__kernel_vsyscall()"....Does this mean, the program breaks by default at 
whatever its doing?  If thats the case, how do I come out of the __kernel_vsyscall() call, to continue within my program?  If I press f8, it comes out, but then I dont know where it was, since I loose the stack trace....Like I said earlier.  Since I cant figure where it was, I dont know where to put breakpoint....

In summary, I want to figureout where my process is stuck or what its doing and try to debug from that point on....

How do I go about this?

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, What I wanted to accomplish was to be able to find where my program is stuck, when it hangs.  I figured it out - It was so simple.  Create a configuration in Eclipse ...."Debug Configurations->C/C++ attach to application"...

Let the process run normally from shell (preferably with a terminal attached). When it hangs, open eclipse, click on the debug icon and run the configured process.  It'll ask you to attach to a process.  Look for your process name and attach to it.

Now, just look at the entire stack trace....you'll see some of your own function calls mixed with kernel function calls.  That tells you where the program is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

1) Attaching to a C process can often cause problems in itself, is there any way for you to start the process in the debugger?

2) Using the step functions of DDD need to be done after you've set a breakpoint and the program is stopped on a command.  From reading your question, I'm not sure you've done that.  You may not want to set many breakpoints, but is setting one or two in critical sections of code possible?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I figured it...pls look at my answer.